Is it possible to override arguments of configuration groups that I instantiate for the purpose of sweeping?
My config file has a controller field that I manually set using CLI options: +controller=mpc. The controller is defined inside the controller group. The filename is mpc.yaml. The content is this:
_target_: ...
_partial_: True
communicator:
  _target_: ...
# learning_rate: !!float 0.5

The controller has an optional field learning_rate that defaults to None. I want to sweep over exactly this parameter.
I used the command python main.py +controller=mpc +controller/learning_rate=0.5. But it does not set the parameter. It adds key-value pair with the name controller/learning_rate. How can I sweep over the learning rate? For example with values 0.5,0.7.

You are confusing config group separator (/) and config object separator (.).
Try:
$ python main.py +controller=mpc +controller.learning_rate=0.5

You can sweep using multirun:
$ python main.py --multirun +controller=mpc +controller.learning_rate=0.5,0.7

As a side note, you probably know that using + tells Hydra to add a new field.
If you had a field with a proper default value, then you wouldn't need to use +.
In that case, Hydra would also give you a better error message when you are trying to override something that is not there.
